# Kronecker Product: finding corresponding indices

Tags: matrices

I've tried to observe a statement from a scientific article on a practical example, but don't understand how are indices on Kronecker product mapped.

The statement is the following:

*If G and H are graphs with adjacency matrices A(G) and A(H) respectively, then the Kronecker product kron(G,H) is defined as the graph with adjacency matrix kron(A(G), A(H)).*

*Edge(Xij,Xkl) is element of kron(G,H) iff (Xi, Xk) is element of G and (Xj,Xl) is element of H where Xij and Xkl are nodes in kron(G,H) and Xi, Xj, Xk and Xl are corresponding nodes in G and H.*

In order to observe how the indices are mapped I tried to calculate the Kronecker product of A and B where
`A = [1 0 1 1; 0 1 0 1; 1 1 0 1; 1 1 1 1]` and `B = [1 0 1; 0 1 1; 1 1 0]`

this results the Kronecker product K

```
K = kron(A, B) = [1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 1; 
0 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 1; 
1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 0; 
0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1; 
0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1; 
0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0; 
1 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1; 
0 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1; 
1 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0; 
1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1; 
0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1; 
1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0]
```

which is 12x12 size matrix. Selecting nodes A(1, 3) = 1 and B(2, 3) = 1 I wanted to find the edge (12, 33) in matrix K but don't understand which row and column are represented with indices 12 and 33.

I would be thankful if anyone could explain how to find appropriate element in matrix K upon given indices from matrix A and B.

Comment: Why not just look at the Wikipedia page on Kronecker products, which has worked examples? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product